# Parsing command-line arguments in Python: array of variable length?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, dynamic-arrays

is it possible to create an array in Python with an variable length?

I'm getting different kind of length from sys.argv when I start the program and I need as much array field as long as the string from sys.argv is.

EDIT for better understanding:

I wrote a python script which can controle the GPIO Ports of a Raspberry Pi

Until now, the script is just able to control one port at the same time. The execute order is like:

```
sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/IO2.py #Port #State (Like high or low)
```

If I want to control Port 5 and set it as High, it would look like that:

```
sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/IO2.py 5 high
```

But NOW, I want to control more ports than just one. It should be look like that:

```
sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/IO2.py 1,4,7,11 high
```

Port 1,4,7,11 are now high.

Comment: Show us an example for how you get "different kind of length from sys.argv". `sys.argv` depends on what command line arguments you pass to your program.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context to your problem? I'm not sure I understand what you want to do.

Comment: python arrays are lists, they are per se of variable length

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. If you want to add an element to a python `list` just use the `append()` or `extend` methods. Or are you using the classes of the `array` module?

Comment: @gefei I don't mean to be rude. I just assume that if the OP used the term `array` then we should either stick to that or specifically ask whether they are actually talking about this or not. Like @Bakuriu did.

Comment: @Tonio no problem. I did not think you were rude. I meant "thanks". I needed the dots since otherwise my comment was too short and SE would not accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a classic example of an XY problem.

Your question has less to do with python arrays, or even python lists, and more to do with how to retrieve the list of options from the command-line arguments. For this you should be using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) rather than trying to parse `sys.argv` manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new empty array like so:

```
a = ["Default value"] * length
```

Where `"Default value"` is the value you want to have in each space (these can obviously be re-assigned..) and `length` is the length you get from `sys.argv`

However, because you can add and remove elements from arrays easily, you may want to re-thing your design?